# Play 2.0 / Scala: loading of module reference configuration broken?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have started to extract some functionality into a separate Play module, together with some default configuration that I put into a file `conf/reference.conf` in the module as described for [Typesafe's `Config` library](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#longer-examples). This configuration gets picked up just fine, e.g. by functional tests run within the context of the module.

But I seem to be running into some classloader issues once I try to start the application depending on said module, e.g. I get some strange complaint from the Akka subsystem:

`No configuration setting found for key 'akka.version'`

This exception goes away once I remove the file `reference.conf` from my module (no other changes), but then obviously the application will not work any more. Currently, the module configuration is in a file `conf/module-reference.conf` which I `include` in the main app's configuration. This works, but I would like to get rid of the `include`.

I suspect that my `reference.conf` somehow shadows the one provided by Akka. Did anybody run into this issue before? And what is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I am victim of some strange file system inconsistencies:

- I am deploying the module to Play's local repository using `play publish-locally`
- This same repository is on Eclipse's build path (created with `play eclipsify`)
- Sometimes, the Play main application seems to pick up the module's JAR when it's broken somehow

#### Workaround:

- close Eclipse
- deploy the module locally
- run a clean build of the main application

Using this procedure, the application's configuration works fine.

#### Tip

While looking into this issue, I came across a useful feature of Typesafe's Config library. You can obtain the whole configuration tree including where each entry comes from using the following line of code:

```
val configDump: String = current.configuration().underlying.root().render()
```

and e.g. dump this to a file for further analysis.